# Why can't I sudo echo a line in /etc/?

Tags: linux, echo, file-permissions, sudo, vi

I am on centos and I did `sudo echo 'testline'>>/etc/test/test` it said `-bash: /etc/test/test: Permission denied`

However, when I do `sudo vi /etc/test/test` and insert `testline` and do `:wq` it writes out fine, why is this happening?

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) autodetects [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2024).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap the whole statement (including the redirect) into a group so the sudo extends around it.

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'testline' >> /etc/test/test"
```

Note: that, too, will fail if `/etc/test` doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 6):

The redirection is processed by the shell prior to running `sudo`, rather than being part of it. Use `tee` instead so that `sudo` runs the process that actually opens the file for writing.

```
echo 'testline' | sudo tee -a /etc/test/test > /dev/null
```

Comment: This is only answer that explains _why_.

Answer (score 0):

Another syntax for the same general solution these guys have already presented:

```
echo "echo 'testline'>>/etc/test/test" | sudo su
```